# End action if webviewdidfinishload

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I habe this code:

```
[MBHUDView hudWithBody:@"" type:MBAlertViewHUDTypeActivityIndicator hidesAfter: show:YES];
```

and at    `hidesAfter:` I do not know.

the MBHUDView should be  hidesAfter webViewFinishLoad. UIWebView is Delegate

I have the same code in another view and there I have use this:

```
[MBHUDView hudWithBody:@"" type:MBAlertViewHUDTypeActivityIndicator hidesAfter:MessageComposeResultSent show:YES];
```

Comment: Wait is UIWebView the delegate of MBHUDView?

Comment: @ evan.stoddard I have only in .h file: `@interface Speisekarte : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    
    IBOutlet UIWebView *pdfviewer;
    
    
    
    IBOutlet UITextField *MeldungInternet;
}
- (BOOL)connected;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *pdfviewer;`

Comment: I haven't really used MBHUDView but did you try `hidesAfter:webViewDidFinishLoad`.  Also does MBHUDView have a hide method in itself.  So you can just define `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad` and then put something like `[MBHUDView hide];` inside?

Comment: No both does not work :( hidesAfter is a float and in MBHUDView there is no hide method -.-